# Is a partially ordered set (poset) a partial algebraic structure?

Tags: functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

If a partially ordered set $(S, \leq)$ is defined by a set $S$ and a partial homogeneous binary relation $\leq$,
then can it be expressed as a partial algebraic structure $(S, f)$,
where $f$ is a partial function $f : S^2 \to \{True, False\}$?

Comment: You can encode a relation as a function, but depending on the sort of algebraic structure you're allowing, it might not be possible to express the properties that make it a partial order as axioms. What's your goal?

Comment: @Karl my goal is to understand what the distinction is between a poset and a partial algebraic structure. Could a poset be thought of as a specialisation of an algebraic structure? Or a specialisation of a partial boolean algebraic structure?

Comment: First, $f$ is defined on its whole domain. Second, the codomain of $f$ should be $S$ in order to get an *operation* on $S$.

Comment: This may be related with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900769/is-a-poset-an-algebra/2901051) which has several answers. But it's not a duplicate, because here something different is being asked. It's related, and the linked question and answers might be useful.