# The analogue, for general partial orders, of commutative idempotent semigroups for semilattices

Tags: order-theory, universal-algebra

I know that the variety of commutative idempotent semigroups, along with the binary relation defined by the open formula $x*y=x$, gives rise to the class of partial orders which are meet-semilattices. Inspired by this, I want to ask, is there a variety of magmas and a corresponding binary relation defined by an open formula in $x$ and $y$, which generates precisely the class of partial orders? If so, can someone give such a variety and a binary relation? And if not, can someone prove it?

Comment: Do you know what happens if we use the same formula, in the variety of magmas given by $$(xy)z=(xy)(yz)?$$ The resulting relation is transitive since if $xy=x$ and $yz=z$ then $xz=(xy)z=(xy)(yz)=xy=x$, so we do indeed get partial orders in this way. Of course, it's not clear to me that we get *all* partial orders this way ...

Comment: Does [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2901051/303170) give any help? The algebras in the papers I mention there are such that the first (Freese & others) is not finitely based, as you can see in the paper (this is not mentioned in the answer); the other two (in the paper from Berman & Blok) they're both finitely based, although I'm not sure they give an explicit equational basis (and these are only for posets with a top element). There may be other reasons for these not to work for you.